Testing Pinia store with setup syntax - how to mock computed fields?
Anyone have idea how can I test Pinia store with @pinia/testing and vitest if I made store with setup syntax. When I use createTestingPinia, I am able to mock computed fields, but actions calls could not be counted. If I use createPinia only, I can't mock computed fields, but store action calls can be counted. Anyone had similar issue? Much appreciated.
I tried to mock computed fields like (using createPinia to set active Pinia):
const store = useStore(); store.someComputedField = computed(() => 1);
If I use createTestingPinia, I am able to mock it like this:
store.someComputedField = 1;
But it's not possible to count store action calls.
I need this because my actions are using computed fields from same store. One important thing is that this is not a problem if I use standard store syntax.
EDIT:
I am posting code to be tried out, to give you more context.
Test:
describe.only('TestStore', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(
            createTestingPinia({
                stubActions: false,
                createSpy: vi.fn,
            })
        );
        vi.clearAllMocks();
    });

    test('Is it possible to mock computed properties and still count action calls?', async () => {
        const testStore = useTestStore();

        vi.spyOn(testStore, 'method1');
        testStore.computedProp = 1;

        expect(testStore.method2()).toBe(1);
        expect(testStore.method1).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    });
});

Store:
export const useTestStore = defineStore('test-store', () => {
    const computedProp = computed(() => 1);

    const method1 = () => {
        return computedProp.value;
    };

    const method2 = () => {
        return method1();
    };

    return {
        method2,
        method1,
        computedProp,
    };
});

Error:
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called once, but got 0 times

Taken from the docs:
// actions are stubbed by default, meaning they don't execute their code by default.
store.someAction()

Meaning you need to do this so actions are not stubbed (but are still spied):
const wrapper = mount(Counter, {
  global: {
    plugins: [createTestingPinia({ stubActions: false })],
  },
})

const store = useSomeStore()

// Now this call WILL execute the implementation defined by the store
store.someAction()

// ...but it's still wrapped with a spy, so you can inspect calls
expect(store.someAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)


I suggest going through the doc, it's well written and has examples on how to test your stores.
EDIT:
Action inside the composition api store is referenced directly and you spy on the export and not the function itself thats inside, so when you call method1 from 2 it calls it directly. On the other hand, for options api, it works because the functions are called by reference and you are spying on the reference itself.

Thanks for taking a look! This makes sense, but it does not solve my problem. Take a look at code snippet I've posted in my original question.

vi.spyOn spies on a module object but in your example you are referencing method1 directly, so it's not intercepted. What you are trying to do is not possible to achieve.

What bugs me is that this is possible with options API store definition. Can you explain why wouldn't this be possible with setup syntax?

It's because the action inside the composition api store is referenced directly and you spy on the export and not the function itself thats inside, so when you call method1 from 2 it calls it directly. On the other hand for options api it works because the functions are called by reference and you are spying on the reference itself.
Here are 2 links to hopefully help you understand more: https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#mocking-pitfalls https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/3548#discussioncomment-6538784

If you wish you can edit your answer and add this explanation - just to give you thumbs up!

I added it as an edit to the original answer, which may also help someone somehow even if its not that relevant, and thanks :).
